# Too much content of 'table_name' are deleted during executing alter distkey command

Tags: amazon-redshift

I've been getting this error when trying to alter sortkeys on a table (the table has ~1M rows x ~12 columns). The table has no sortkeys before doing the alter as seen below:

```
alter table table_name
alter sortkey (date_col, col2, col3);
```

This tries to run for a few seconds before returning the following:

```
ERROR: Too much content of 'table_name' are deleted during executing alter distkey command. Please Retry.
```

Has anyone run into this particular error before? My solution has been to create a new table with my desired sortkeys, which works fine.

```
create table table_name_sorted
sortkey (date_col, col2, col3)
as (
  select * from table_name
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the _exact_ error message? It mentions `alter distkey`, but your command is `alter sortkey`.

Comment: [Amazon Redshift now supports changing table sort keys dynamically](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-redshift-supports-changing-table-sort-keys-dynamically/) mentions that this "feature is available in Redshift 1.0.10654 and later". Does this match your Redshift version?

Comment: Yeah @JohnRotenstein that's correct. And I am on a more recent version of Redshift. Thanks

Comment: How is table `table_name` currently distributed? Does it have a distribution key manually defined?

Comment: @NathanGriffiths I specified no distribution keys when creating the table